# Cannot load data on WebView

Tags: android, webview

I can't load this data on Web View. Only replacing data is worked but data is not displayed in HTML format, it display as a plain String.

```
String data = "\\u003cp style=\"text-align: justify;\"\\u003e\\u003cspan style=\"font-size: 18px;\"\\u003eलाभांश पारित गर्न पुस ३० गते आइतबार आह्वान गरिएको एघारौं वार्षिक साधारण सभाका लागि कम्पनी सञ्चालक समतिको पुस ८ गते बसेको ८०३ औं बैठकले पुस १५ गते आइतबारदेखि पुस ३० गतेसम्म शेयरधनी दर्ता पुस्तिका बन्द गर्ने निर्णय गरेकाे छ ।\\u0026nbsp;\\u003c/span\\u003e\\u003c/p\\u003e\\n\\u003cp style=\"text-align: justify;\"\\u003e\\u003cspan style=\"font-size: 18px;\"\\u003eयसअनुसार बुकक्लोजको अघिल्लो कारोबार दिन अर्थात पुस १२ गते बिहीबारसम्म कायम रहने शेयरधनी मात्र लाभांशका लागि योग्य हुनेछन् । \\u003c/span\\u003e\\u003c/p\\u003e\\n\\u003cp style=\"text-align: justify;\"\\u003e\\u003cspan style=\"font-size: 18px;\"\\u003e\\u003cimg class=\"img-right\" src=\"../Uploads/Repository/636148043052799287.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"320\" height=\"240\" /\\u003eटेलिकमको पुस २ गते सम्पन्न सञ्चालक समितिको ८०२ औं बैठकले अघिल्लो आर्थिक वर्षमा पति नै प्रतिशेयर ५५ रुपैयाँ नगद लाभांश वितरण गर्ने प्रस्ताव गरेको थियो । \\u003c/span\\u003e\\u003c/p\\u003e\\n\\u003cp style=\"text-align: justify;\"\\u003e\\u003cspan style=\"font-size: 18px;\"\\u003eटेलिकमको ११ औं वार्षिक साधारण सभाले अनुमोदन गरेपश्चात शेयरधनीलाई लाभांश वितरण हुनेछ । सभाले चालू आवको लागि लेखापरिक्षक नियुक्त गरि पारिश्रमिक निर्धारण समेत गर्नेछ ।\\u003c/span\\u003e\\u003c/p\\u003e\\n\\u003cp style=\"text-align: justify;\"\\u003e\\u003cspan style=\"font-size: 18px;\"\\u003e१५ अर्ब रुपैयाँ चुक्ता पूँजी रहेको टेलिकमको जगेडा कोषमा ८७ अर्ब ९८ करोड ९३ लाख २५ हजार ७१५ रुपैयाँ छ । चालु आर्थिक वर्षको पहिलो त्रैमासमा टेलिकमले ४ अर्ब ४९ करोड ६ लाख ४४ हजार ५२१ रुपैयाँ खुद नाफा कमाएर प्रतिशेयर आम्दानी ११९ रुपैयाँ ७५ पैसा कायम गरेको छ ।\\u003c/span\\u003e\\u003c/p\\u003e";
webView.getSetting().setMixedContentMode(MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
String filterFirst = data.replace("../Uploads", "myurl");
webView.loadData(filterSecond,"text/html; charset=utf-8","utf-8");
```

Comment: Sorry Data is not in HTML format so I can't display this data as HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced this problem when you don't have the HTML data. Here you have to follow

> Declare property in string.xml

```
 <string name="html_arrangement" translatable="false">
        <![CDATA[<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">]]>
    </string>
```

> Then use it for your data display screen

Here `data.getDescription()` will be your data

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", getString(R.string.html_arrangement) + data.getDescription(),"text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Create the html file, put your html data in it. Once it is done, put this file in app's  /assets directory and load file into WebView as:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Solution 2:

```
String yourData ="<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>";
webview.loadData(yourData, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Html.fromHtml(somestring) to format your data into HTML format

Comment: Not in a WebView.